# How do I create empty lists in a numpy Boolean array that identifies empty lists?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kdtree, scipy-spatial

I am trying to create a Boolean array that identifies empty lists in an array. I did the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

rand_points = np.random.rand(5,3)

other_points = np.zeros((5,3))
for i in range(3):
   other_points[:,i] = rand_points[:,i] * 2

randTree = cKDTree(rand_points)
nearPoints = cKDTree.query_ball_point(randTree, other_points, 0.6)
```

`nearPoints` can produce the following output:

```
array([list([]), list([]), list([2]), list([]), list([])], dtype=object)
```

I would like to produce a Boolean array that selects elements equal to `list([ ])` as `True`. I have tried multiple approaches, but have not succeeded, such as:

```
nearPoints == None
```

How would I correctly create a Boolean array?

Comment: I fixed some presumably copy-paste bugs in your code, please make sure it's what you intended to write.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much performance to speak of if you have arrays with `dtype=object`, and apparently this is indeed what [`cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point) gives you. So might as well just create the array with a list comprehension:

```
>>> np.array([len(lst)==0 for lst in nearPoints])
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True])
```

Or if you prefer `map` over a list comprehension (I don't):

```
~np.fromiter(map(len, nearPoints), dtype=bool)
```

On a higher level, there's probably not much you can do in terms of vectorized operations with such an array of lists, so you'll probably end up iterating over the array anyway. But then you can do

```
for lst in nearPoints:
    if not lst:
        # skip empty list cases
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
~nearPoints.astype(bool)
```

Comment: Ah, nice catch, this has to be the simplest and fastest answer.